# What's the default value for a DecimalField in Django?

Tags: django

I'm adding a new DecimalField to my model, what value will it have by default in the database (if I don't specify the default explicitly on the field e.g. default=1.23)?

```
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3)
```

I'm expecting it will be either NULL or 0.0 (or None or Decimal(0.000) in python), but which?

Couldn't find this mentioned in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield

I'm using Django 2.2, but expect this is consistent across versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django does not set any default values. You must specify the default value yourself.

```
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3, default=0.0)
```

Comment: Ran makemigrations when testing this, which gave `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'amount' to mymodel without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).` ... so yes, can confirm that Django ensures the developer specifies a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your definition. The default value would be `0.000`

If you had keyword argument `null=True` then you may expect `NULL` where a value has not been entered in.

Comment: Just been testing it and ran makemigrations, which gave `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'amount' to mymodel without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).` ... so looks like Django ensures a default is specified... at least if `null=True` has not been specified.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the default value should be NULL but it will happen only when you activate it i.e. by setting `null = True` as one of the attributes to the model field. I haven't checked it recently though.
However, I recommend setting default value by yourself. e.g. `default = 0.000`.

Alternatively, you need to pass another attribute similar to `blank = True` or `required = False` if you want the model field to be an **optional field**. Otherwise, it will always prompt you to fill some decimal value in it.